# Uniformly distribute the Kafka partitions among the Consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a topic with 300 partitions, and have 100 Consumers/Machines. I am using Spring Kafka as my underlying framework to implement the Kafka Consumers.

I am using ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory and setting the concurrency to 3, so in theory, I should have 300 Consumer Containers, and one partition should be connected to one container, thus the partitions being uniformly distributed among the 100 machines.

> For the first constructor, kafka will distribute the partitions across the consumers. For the second constructor, the ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer distributes the TopicPartition s across the delegate KafkaMessageListenerContainer s.
>
> If, say, 6 TopicPartition s are provided and the concurrency is 3; each container will get 2 partitions. For 5 TopicPartition s, 2 containers will get 2 partitions and the third will get 1. If the concurrency is greater than the number of TopicPartitions, the concurrency will be adjusted down such that each container will get one partition.

But I don't see the above behavior, I see that some of the Containers/Machines are Idle, while others are connected to 6 partitions, which is causing Lag in Kafka Topic.

Am I doing something wrong here, how can I make sure that the partitions are evenly mapped between the Containers and no container is mapped to more than one partition? Please help.

```
key.deserializer : StringDeserializer
value.deserializer : [CUSTOM DESERIALIZER]
enable.auto.commit  : false
max.poll.records : 5
group.id : [MY GROUP]
partition.assignment.strategy : StickyAssignor
max.partition.fetch.bytes : 1048576
bootstrap.servers : [SERVERS]
auto.commit.interval.ms : 3000
auto.offset.reset : latest


factory.setConcurrency(3);

@KafkaListener(topics = "#{kafkaTopicConfig.getStoreSupply()}", containerFactory = EI_LISTNER_FACTORY)
```

EI_LISTNER_FACTORY is a Bean..

```
@Bean(EI_LISTNER_FACTORY)
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, AggQuantityByPrimeValue> eiKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

    Boolean eiCnsumerStartup = [START_UP From Configuration]

    Integer concurrentThreadCount = 3;

    Map<String, Object> config = [properties from ABOVE]
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, AggQuantityByPrimeValue> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config));
    factory.setAutoStartup(eiConsumerStartup);

    if (config.get(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG).equals("false")) {
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.setConcurrency(concurrentThreadCount);
    }
    return factory;
```

}

Comment: is your application running in one server ? or multiple servers ? and are you using same consumer group id ?

Comment: It is running on multiple servers.. Yes I am using same Consumer group ID @Deadpool

Comment: have you tried these commands to find the consumer position https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_lag

Comment: Edit the question to show your container configuration.

Comment: @GaryRussell updated the question.

Comment: @Deadpool yes I have, I see in cases where 6 partitions are assigned to a single Server same consumer-id is assigned to two partitions.

Comment: I need to see the container (or `@KafkaListener`) configuration.

Comment: @GaryRussell updated

Comment: Thanks; I was just trying to understand why you pasted information about the "second constructor" when you are not using it (I needed to be sure). I see nothing in that configuration that would prevent even distribution. You should look at the logs for "partitions assigned"  and "partitions revoked" INFO messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Config looks fine. Probably when you described consumer group, few consumers had gone unreachable/idle. Thus rebalancing would have caused to assign same server container thread to multiple partition.

If this is not the case, Enable kafka level logs to monitor the partition assigned and revoked logs to check if rebalance is triggering the desired outcome.

Comment: Is it advised to write our own Assignor for this?

Comment: If you want only once semantics and want to control how the reassignment takes place then you will have to write your own assignor.

Comment: Actually I found the issue, I logged into all the idle servers and found the Consumers were not running properly and were thus unreachable. Thank you for the Suggestion. One more issue I have seen for the same topic is that, when the inbound to the topic increases Consumer throughput decreases, why would we see this behavior?

Comment: Glad that it could help you. Don't see any correlation between increasing inbound to the topic Consumer throughput decreases. Check the configuration for max poll records on consumer side and batch size on producer end, if they are helpful.